# Disabling UAC (Windows 10) for Administrator accounts

Tags: windows-10, administration, uac

To help improve the user experience on admin workstations, would it be ok to disable the UAC or maybe set it with a more permissive mode?

Comment: What do you mean by "would it be ok?" For user experience? For security? For compliance with regulations? For best practice? Are you aware of what UAC is for?

Comment: Not only "would it be OK", but what does "Administrator" or "admin workstations" mean? The built-in Administrator account already has UAC disabled by default (but you're also not supposed to use that account except as a last-ditch system repair account). If you want a dedicated "do admin stuff" account on Windows you can re-enable that account, or use a domain admin (though the latter is... risky). If you're asking about the day-to-day accounts of normal employees on everyday workstations, that's a slightly different thing.